# What's the difference between the representation of a line and that of a line segment?

Tags: mathematics, graphics-programming

What is the difference between a line and a line segment from the implementation point of view?

To me, line segment means:

```
class LineSegment2d
{
Point2d start, end;
public:
    ......
}
```

This representation should be enough to represent a line for any practical purpose in CG. But how do we describe a line and distinguish it from a line-segment?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about game development.

Comment: If this is not related to game programming then I can argue that any linear algebra or geometry questions are not related to gamedev...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, a line has no beginning or end. It is infinite in length. For disambiguation, this is often called a ray in graphics programming. A line of this type is described by any point on the line plus a direction.

A line segment is what most people are referring to when they say 'a line'. It has a beginning and an end point. It's common to refer to a line segment simply as a line, since we don't normally deal with lines of infinite length.

Computationally, they are identical. While it's possible to represent an infinite line with only an origin and a direction of arbitrary length, it's impossible to perform calculations on infinities so lines are generally handled the same as line segments, either as two points or as an origin plus a vector (direction with length). It's basically free to store an implicit working length in the direction vector anyway. The only difference is in the inherent meaning. A line segment connects two points, whereas a line or ray passes through two points.

pseudo-code:

```
// 1. defined with {point, point}
lineRay = {{1,2} , {2,3}}
lineSegment = {{1,2} , {2,3}}

// 2. defined with {origin, vector}
lineRay = {{1,2} , {1,1}}
lineSegment = {{1,2} , {1,1}}
```

Here, the lineRay and lineSegment are identical in both definitions. The only difference between the lineRay and lineSegment is in the implied meaning of the points. The difference between the two methods of definition is strategic, depending on how the lines will be used. Graphics are represented with points whereas calculations are generally performed using the vector format. They are also easily converted between by adding or subtracting the origin point.

If for example, you were calculating the intersection of two (non-parallel) unbounded lines (rays) you would simply find the intersection point and return it. If one or both lines are bounded (line segments), you would find the intersection point, then you would perform extra checks to determine if the point falls within the bounds of the segment.

The first method could also be thought of as two vectors where the origin is at {0,0}.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what exactly you are looking for but line segments are commonly described by their endpoints, or by a point, a normalized direction vector and a length.  Another way would be a starting point and a non normalized direction vector which also is the length.

For the purposes of raytracing, I usually use that second form (starting point, normalized direction and length).

The third form could be good if you wanted to work in a parameterized 0 to 1 value "time t".  You multiply your time t value by the direction vector and add it to the starting point. This would be useful for moving something from one point to another over time.

Lines can also be described by two points on the line, or by a single point and a direction vector that may or may not be normalized.

There are also of course other ways to describe a line mathematically, but these are the ways I've seen most often in game development.

Does that help at all? If not lemme know, I might have better info for you.